# Unable to swap ERC20 AMIS token with other tokens missing something need help from experts.

Tags: tokens

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa23ca275a19caf9a753ce020a75c264e0b0d1674

As of today the value is in 1000$ per token i have 11 tokens ready to give 1 token amount whoever can solve the fuction issue.

I have tried to swap with other coins on 0xproject the function is not executing. There muat be some issue with function or it may be missing.  Need help in solving the issue.

URGENTLY NEED TO SWAP AND SELL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Try to use EtherDelta

> One can start trading AMIS against 13 major ETH Assets on the
>   etherdelta decentralized exchange platform, all of which are ETH based
>   trading pairs:
>
> One can either decide to Buy/Sell AMIS against ETH
>   https://etherdelta.com/#0x949bed886c739f1a3273629b3320db0c5024c719-ETH

You can import your account at the top right. You need to know the address and the private key to import your account.

After selecting your account you can place new sell order AMIS/Ether.

---

*Quote from [the ERC20 Token AMIS information site](https://erc20amis.wordpress.com/2017/03/23/easy-amis-trading-on-etherdelta/).*

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

I cant do that at etherdelta / idex / cryptoderivatives the AMIS is being sold at a price of peanut whereas the token value is of gold.

I think they are selling coins at exchanges not token i am holding AMIS Token.

Comment: Confusions : 

* some say i need to sell on etherdelta or idex or cryptoderevatives but there the buy order are less than .5$
* some say i can swap that AMIS token to other tokens (tried on 0xproject everthing seems fine but the order dosent complete )
* some say i need to sell it to the AMIS contract
* some say i need to create AMIS contract and keep it in blockchain ( no idea)

Comment: Is it possible to swap with other token/coin ? 
like AMIS/Gnosis

Comment: I haven't found any token swap service for AMIS so far. Have you tried to set price yourself on etherdelta? I saw AMIS tokens were sent to [etherdelta_2](https://etherscan.io/address/0x8d12a197cb00d4747a1fe03395095ce2a5cc6819#tokentxns) contract, but the last transfer was days ago. And according to [etherscan](https://etherscan.io/token/0x949bEd886c739f1A3273629b3320db0C5024c719) last AMIS token transfer was `2 days 1 hr ago`.

Comment: Yes i tried to set price and sell on etherdelta, Thats not the right decision its very low price. we need to swap with other token and sell that new token and earn ETH.

Some dev said i am missing the smart contract function in the blockchain thats the reason unable to complete the swap.

Understand this : I bought AMIS token but the exchanges are trading AMIS coins not tokens. 

I am holding token of AMIS not coins.

Answer (score 0):

The AMIS ERC20 Tokens cryptographic assets have been successfully tested to be traded on 0x relayers and decentralized exchanges for quite sometime; it has been proven that AMIS is resistant to the recent bugs affecting some ERC20 tokens.

For the list of decentralized exchanges and 0x relayers - **Bamboo Relay** and **Token Store** - serving AMIS investors best interest; see details by checking [https://github.com/amisolution/ERC20-AMIS/wiki/Get-AMIS][1].

For the list of bugs against which AMIS coin is armored, one can verify that the AMIS contract is proof resistant against 3 major bugs
[New batchOverflow Bug in Multiple ERC20 Smart Contracts (CVE-2018-10299)][2]
[New proxyOverflow Bug in Multiple ERC20 Smart Contracts (CVE-2018-10376) (PeckShield)][3]
[PeckShield discovered a new vulnerability named transferFlaw (CVE-2018–10468)][4]

*References*

- [1]: https://github.com/amisolution/ERC20-AMIS/wiki/Get-AMIS "AMIS
  Github Wiki"
- [2]:    https://www.peckshield.com/2018/04/22/batchOverflow/
- [3]:    https://peckshield.com/2018/04/25/proxyOverflow/
- [4]:    https://peckshield.com/2018/04/28/transferFlaw/